# Alinhamento de elementos no header

Tags: html, div, posicionamento, css

Sou programador e há muito tempo não manipulo **HTML/CSS**, agora estou necessitando criar um portal para uma pequena aplicação e estou com dificuldade em algumas questões relacionadas a alinhamento de elementos com CSS.

Necessito manter a **barra de pesquisa no centro** como já está, e colocar o **link de logout lá no canto direito da barra superior**, porém não estou conseguindo alinhar os elementos no header.

Se alguém puder me ensinar eu agradeço muito, pesquisei bastante sobre os parametros de alinhamento, mas estou um pouco confuso.

```css
/* Template de cards para exibir os elementos */
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;700;800&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #232427;
}

body .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 40px 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

body .container .card {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 320px;
  height: 380px;
  box-shadow: inset 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), inset -5px -5px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1), 5px 5px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), -5px -5px 15px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 30px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

img {
  border-radius: 80%;
}

body .container .card .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  background: #2a2b2f;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body .container .card .box:hover {
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

body .container .card .box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
}

body .container .card .box .content {
  padding: 20px 5px 20px 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

body .container .card .box .content h2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  /* original: -10px */
  right: 10px;
  /* original: 30px */
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

body .container .card .box .content h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  color: #1ea6f598;
}

body .container .card .box .content p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body .container .card .box .content a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  background: #2196f3;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

body .container .card .box .content a:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: rgba(165, 27, 27, 0.705);
  color: white;
}




/* Estilo da barra de pesquisa no topo do site */
#click {
  display: none;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main label {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgb(30, 166, 245);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .6s;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  left: 11px;
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  transition: .4s;
}

span:nth-child(2), span:nth-child(3) {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  top: 31px;
  left: 26px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  transition: .5s;
}

#barraSuperior {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 35px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #202124;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 99;
}

#barraSuperior a {
  color: #c01111;
}

.main #barraPesquisa {
  position: absolute;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50px;
  color: #2196f3;
  transition: .6s;
}

#click:checked~.main #barraPesquisa {
  width: 300px;
}

#click:checked~.main label {
  margin-left: 250px;
}

#click:checked~.main span:nth-child(1) {
  opacity: 0;
}

#click:checked~.main span:nth-child(2), #click:checked~.main span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 22px;
  left: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 5px;
}

#click:checked~.main #barraPesquisa {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgb(90, 217, 255);
}

#click:checked~.main span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}




/* Estilo do loading do site ao abrir */
div#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: block;
}

div#loader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: #eee;
  background-image: url('../img/load.gif');
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Tele Conteúdo</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loader"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).on('load', function() {
        jQuery("#loader").delay(400).fadeOut("slow");
    });
  </script>
  <header id="barraSuperior">
  <a href="#">Sair do sistema></a>
    <input id="click" type="checkbox">
    <div class="main">
      <input type="text" id="barraPesquisa" autocomplete="off">
      <label for="click">
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: já tentou colocar no `#barraSuperior a { float: right }`?

Comment: #barraSuperior {text-align: right}

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar a propriedade `right` na sua tag do logout, e definir a distância da margem direita. Junto do `position: absolute;`

Ficaria assim seu estilo:

```
#barraSuperior a {
  color: #c01111;
  
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;

}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Agradeço pela sua contribuição! :)